# running .exe programs on Mac OSX

Tags: windows, macos, osx-snow-leopard

My question is actually fairly simple: is there any way i could run windows programs (for example PC games) on my iMac? (i am currently running OSX Snow Leopard). I know about things like VirtualBox and Parallels to run windows itself, but is there a Mac application that will allow me to run .exe programs and the like?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get would be using [WINE](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX), however, the list is relatively limited as to what it can run (especially on Mac).  As for games, there is [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/) - which is getting decent - but still not native speeds of a normal OS.

The absolute best way to run Windows applications would be to set up [BootCamp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461) and dual boot (that way you have *real* Windows and *real* OSX, not OSX and an emulated, kind-of Windows that is bug laden.

Comment: well i have VirtualBox, but i have never been able to make a game work on it (thats a different issue altogether)

Comment: Yeah, VB doesn't support full hardware usage and leaks performance.  3/4 of that is because you are essentially running an OS on an OS's hardware, so the first one degrades and the second one does not get all the resources.

Comment: huh. stinks, but i gotta say that makes some sense though

Comment: Agreed.  But DualBooting is easy enough - if you are okay trying that.  It will be the best performance.

Comment: seems that way. i just want to avoid that though if i can. seems like i cant

Comment: Yeah, I saw your post on Crossover.  No doubt it is the best way.  Other ways may work - but there will be glitches.